# How can I convert a string generated from user input into a list or integer?

Tags: python, string

I need to create a script that calculates the distance between two coordinates. The issue I'm having though is when I assign the coordinate to object one, it is stored as a string and am unable to convert it to a list or integer/float. How can I convert this into either a list or integer/float? The script and error I get is below.

---

Script:

```
one=input("Enter an x,y coordinate.")
Enter an x,y coordinate. 1,7

int(1,7)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-76-67de81c91c02>", line 1, in <module>
    int(1,7)
  TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base
```

Comment: `x,y = map(int, input("Enter an x,y coordinate.").split(","))` ?

Comment: Python docs are great. So [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) is a built in function which when 2 arguments are given, the second argument is the base.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the entered string to int/float by first splitting the string into the point components, then casting to the appropriate type:

```
x, y = map(float, one.split(','))
```

To keep the entered values as a single custom datatype, named `Point` for example, you can use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')
>>> Point(*map(float, '1, 2'.split(',')))
Point(x=1.0, y=2.0)
>>> _.x, _.y
(1.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `namedtuple` - that's probably more appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input into the specific type as int or float

Into a list:

```
_list = list(map(int, input("Enter an x,y coordinate.").split(",")))
```

or into variables:

```
a, b = map(int, input("Enter an x,y coordinate.").split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

After this `one=input("Enter an x,y coordinate.")` the variable **one** contains a string that looks like this `'x, y'` which cannot be converted to `int` as is.

You need to first split the string using `str.split(',')` which will yield a list `[x,y]` then you can iterate through the list and convert each of `x` and `y` to `int` using `map` which applies the `int(..)` function to every element of the list `[x, y]`.

In code, you can do it as follows:

```
one=input("Enter an x,y coordinate.")
x, y = map(int, one.split(','))
```

As a side note, you should consider wrapping the user input with a `try .. except` clause to handle the case where a user inserts non-int input:

```
try: 
    one=input("Enter an x,y coordinate.")
    x, y = map(int, one.split(','))
except Exception as e: 
    print("Please provide a valid input")
```